# Access children element I'm appending with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a reason I can't access the `children()` element I'm appending?

This code adds `default color blue color` to all tags on this question page.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $.each($('li.d-inline.mr4.js-post-tag-list-item'), function() {
    const e = $(this);
    const h = `<span id="span1">default color <span id="span2">blue color</span></span>`;
    var el = e.find('#span1');
    
    if (el.length === 0) {
      e.append(h);
      el.children().css({
        'color': 'blue',
        'font-style': 'italic',
        'font-weight': 'bold'
      });
      
      console.log.apply(console, el);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- put some HTML here, please -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: 1 problem, if you have multiple `li` elements then you insert multiple elements with the same id, aka span1 and span2

Comment: As far as I know it is not forbidden. Many pages create multiple elements with the same id. Try `#metadata-line` on YouTube search page.

Comment: Neret Id should always be unique. If you run $("span1") it would always target the first element with the id, never others.

Comment: [IDs must be unique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9454716/1264804). It's invalid HTML to do otherwise. There's no need to use an ID anyway. You can reference a class by traversal.

Comment: Protip: One-letter variable names will not make you any friends. Name them semantically.

Comment: Please put some HTML and your script in a demo snippet using the editor. I'm not clear on what you're doing with `h`. Does `#span1` already exist in the page elsewhere?

Comment: @isherwood I'm appending HTML `h`. `#span1` does not exist anywhere else on the page.

Comment: Then `var el = e.find('#span1');` doesn't make much sense. Please do as I asked so we have something clear to discuss. Otherwise I can't help.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that even after appending your new element (h), then your variables haven't updated. So after the append do:

```
el = e.find('#span1');
```

as in:

```
e.append(h);
el = e.find('#span1'); // <- you need to update the variable.
```

**Demo**

```js
!function() {
  "use strict";

  $(document).ready(() => {
    $.each($('li.d-inline.mr4.js-post-tag-list-item'), function() {
      const e = $(this);
      const h = `<span id="span1"><span id="span2">999</span></span>`;
      var el = e.find('#span1');
      if (el.length === 0) {
        e.append(h);
        el = e.find('#span1');
        el.children().css({'color': 'blue', 'font-style': 'italic', 'font-weight': 'bold'});
        console.log.apply(console, el);
      }
    });
  });
}();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="d-inline mr4 js-post-tag-list-item"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I want `#span1` to be the default color and `#span2` to be blue.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn't know the id must be unique. I found what the problem was. After appending html `e.append(h)` you need to re-find the element `el = e.find('#span1')` and its `el.children()`.